# FocusTraversalPolicy losing focus on getComponentBefore()

Tags: java, swing, focus

I'm trying to create a custom focus traversal policy for my swing app by passing a list of components (I do this as the traversal required is not the same as the Containers component order). Like this example:

```
public class ComponentTraversal extends FocusTraversalPolicy
{
    private final java.util.List<Component> componentList;

    public ComponentTraversal(java.util.List<Component> aList)
    {
        componentList = aList;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer, Component aComponent)
    {
        int index = componentList.indexOf(aComponent);
        if (index == (componentList.size() - 1))
            index = -1;
        return componentList.get(index + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer, Component aComponent)
    {
        int index = componentList.indexOf(aComponent);
        if (index == 0)
            index = componentList.size();
        return componentList.get(index - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer)
    {
        return componentList.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer)
    {
        return componentList.get(componentList.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer)
    {
        return componentList.get(0);
    }

}
```

And run with this test class:

```
public class C extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    new C();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public C()
    {
        super("A Test");
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));

        JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField();

        jp.add(jtf1);
        jp.add(jtf2);

        java.util.List<Component> comps = new ArrayList<Component>();
        comps.add(jtf1);
        comps.add(jtf2);  //This line

        this.add(jp);
        this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new ComponentTraversal(comps));
        this.setSize(200,100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

In most cases this works fine, as posted will work in both directions. If I comment out the line with the comment `This line` (i.e. adding only one component to the traversal list) it will work in the forwards direction (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)... retaining focus on itself.

But if I do it in reverse direction (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), the component loses focus and no exceptions are reported.

This isn't really a problem in terms of my application, as there will always be more than one component, but I tried this out and it bugs me and I was wondering if anyone had encountered this before, or knows what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The component is still visible and on the screen - It's just not added to the list that is used in the traversal policy.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Though I think you might not be entirely wrong. If I extend it to include the checks for focusable, enabled and visible and add a third component which is not visible I get similar behavior.

Comment: This "could" be a bug.  What's happening is basically the private `requestFocusInWindow` is returning `false`.  When moving forward, there is a flag called `clearOnFailure` which is normally set to `false`. This stops the method from calling `clearGlobalFocusOwner` on the `KeyboardFocusManager`. This however, is being ignored in `transferFocusBackward`.  What it doesn't seem capable of doing is determining that the component that focus is going to is the same component that has focus...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah it is, or was... fixed in 8 at least. See this [Bug Report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7081012).